# jQuery $.POST not working - Add a variable in $_SESSION

Tags: jquery, .post

I have a file named "test.php" with a link to "test2.php":

```
<a href="test2.php" id="test">Test</a>
```

In my test2.php, I check the $_SESSION variable:

```
<?php session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

When I click on the link in the "test.php" file, I want to add data in the $_SESSION variable, so here is my js:

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
   $.post('test3.php', { myvar : 'myvalue' } );
});
```

And on the "test3.php" file, I have this piece of code:

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['myvar'] = $_POST['myvar'];
```

I don't understand why it's not working... In the "test2.php" file, the $_SESSION['myvar'] does not exist.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you get redirected to 'test2.php' when you click in the link ? if yes, your $.post will not executed

Comment: Perhaps you get redirected to test2.php before the request sent to test3.php is finished?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! If I do a e.preventDefault(); (to prevent the redirection to test2.php), it's working. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to `test3.php` will be cancelled, because you're not preventing the default behaviour of following the link to `test2.php`.

Try the following;

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
   $.post('test3.php', { myvar : 'myvalue' } );
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can then redirect to `test2.php` when the request completes;

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
   var that = this;

   $.post('test3.php', { myvar : 'myvalue' } ).done(function () {
       window.location.href = that.href;
   });

   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change little bit of your code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test">Test</a>
```

and

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
   $.post('test3.php', { myvar : 'myvalue' } ,function(){
window.location.reload('test2.php');//opening page here

});
});
```

this should work